# How to get Top Activity in Android 5.0 +

Tags: android, android-activity, process

I'm using below code to get Top Activity

```
private String getTopPackageName() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    } else {
        final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pis = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo pi : pis) {
            if (pi.pkgList.length == 1) return pi.pkgList[0];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

It word on API<21 but API>=21 it return "" :(
How to get that?
I will try:

```
private void printForegroundTask() {
String currentApp = "NULL";
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
    if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
            currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }
} else {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
}

Log.e(TAG, "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);
```

}

BUT return NULL :( please help me! thanks

Comment: `getRunningTasks` is deprecated.

Comment: I know that but when instead by UsageStatsManager not working? It return null, 
I have missed something , but I do not know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Accessibility Services but for that you need to redirect your users to the Accessibility Settings to turn it on. Sample code is below to get the package of the app which has been just opened or in your case the top activity.

```
  public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
             String packageName = event.getPackageName();

        }
  }
```

Comment: Great! You save my day. Thanksyou!

Answer (score 1):

[`getRunningTasks()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) is deprecated in **API level 21(Lollipop)**

As alternate you can do like this

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> task = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).importanceReasonComponent;
String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName()
```

Note:

> this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces. This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here.

[Refer the doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))

**UPDATE:**

```
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> task = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = null;

    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo singleTask : task){
        if(singleTask.importanceReasonComponent !=null){
            runningAppProcessInfo = singleTask;
            break;
            }
    }

    if(runningAppProcessInfo!=null) {
        ComponentName componentInfo = runningAppProcessInfo.importanceReasonComponent;
        String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
        Log.d("myPackageName", packageName);
    }
```

Comment: i had that :
private String getTopPackageName() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    } else {
        final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pis = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo pi : pis) {
            if (pi.pkgList.length == 1) return pi.pkgList[0];
        }
    }
    return "";
}

Comment: what does it returns? null?

Comment: OK wait I will see

Comment: It return null when test on android 5.1 :(

Comment: Did you copy the same codes ? and still returning null ?

Comment: above android 5.1 this code doesn't work. I will try use  Accessibility Services  and success. Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

you need use permission **"PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"** for UsageStatsManager:

"This API requires the permission **android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS**, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application."

Refer:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html